# How to join elements of a sublist with a pipe?

Tags: python

I have a list of the form:

`names = [['123, jack',['jack johnson, jack richards, jack michaels']],['325, nick',['nick thompson, nick jacobs, nick smith']],....]`.

in which each generic first name has an id associated with it, while a sublist for that element contains every full name starting with the generic first name.

I would like to change every element of the sublist containing the full names and replace the commas with pipes, in order to give a list in the form of:

`names = [['123, jack',['jack johnson| jack richards| jack michaels']],['325, nick',['nick thompson| nick jacobs| nick smith']],....]`.

Is there an optimal way to iterate through the list and replace as such?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a nested list comprehension, and use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/string-methods.html) with [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/string-methods.html) in order change the inner list separators:

```
[i + ['| '.join(j)] for *i, j in names]

[['123, jack', 'jack johnson| jack richards| jack michaels'],
 ['325, nick', 'nick thompson| nick jacobs| nick smith']]
```

---

Note that by using [extended iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) this will work with an arbitrary amount of strings prior to the sublists. For instance, with this other example:

```
names = [['123, jack', 'MORE STRINGS', ['jack johnson', 'jack richards', 'jack michaels']],
         ['325, nick',['nick thompson', 'nick jacobs', 'nick smith']]]

[i + ['| '.join(j)] for *i, j in names]

[['123, jack', 'MORE STRINGS', 'jack johnson| jack richards| jack michaels'],
 ['325, nick', 'nick thompson| nick jacobs| nick smith']]
```